# Vb6.0 Abrir un array de Imagenes

Tags: vb6

estoy intentado guardar una lista de nombres de imágenes y después abrirlos, pero no funciona.

"Por ahora, solo abre una imagen de cada guía."

Pueden ayudarme, este es mi código.

```
Public Function ObtenerImagePath(id As Long) As String
Dim rtn As String
Dim ctrl As New SqliteHelper
Dim rs As cRecordset
Dim query As String
Dim unaimagen As String
Dim variasimagenes As String
query = "SELECT * FROM IMEI WHERE Codigo = " & CStr(id) & ";"
Set rs = ctrl.ExecuteRecordset(query)
If (Not rs.EOF) Then
    Dim guia As String
    Dim fecha As String
    Dim tmp() As String
    guia = Trim(rs("Guia"))
    fecha = rs("FechaEmi")
    tmp = Split(fecha, "/")
    unaimagen = Dir(cdPhysicalPath & "Imagenes\" & tmp(2) & tmp(1) & "\" & 
    guia & ".*")
    variasimagenes = Dir(cdPhysicalPath & "Imagenes\" & tmp(2) & tmp(1) & 
    "\" & guia & "_*") 'Aqui deberia guardar varios nombres de imagen o algo 
    'así. ejemplo. 
    '"013406617__1212.TIF","013406617__copia1.TIF","013406617__copia2.TIF".

    If Len(unaimagen) > 0 Then

    rtn = cdPhysicalPath & "Imagenes\" & tmp(2) & tmp(1) & "\" & unaimagen
    ElseIf Len(variasimagenes) > 0 Then

    rtn = cdPhysicalPath & "Imagenes\" & tmp(2) & tmp(1) & "\" & 
    variasimagenes
    Else
    rtn = ""
    End If

    End If
    ObtenerImagePath = rtn   '--> Aquí es donde debería alojar los nombres 
    'de imagen y abrirlos.
    End Function
```

[image: Formulario para buscar y ver la imagen o imágenes!!!]

Y este código, muestra la imagen:

```
Private Sub btnVer_Click()
     On Error GoTo btnVer_error
     Dim id As Long
     id = ObtenerIdSeleccionado()

     If (id <= 0) Then
     MsgBox "Seleccione un registro.", vbInformation, "INFO"
     Exit Sub
     End If

     If (Not ValidInCD(id)) Then
     Exit Sub
     End If

     Dim path As String
     path = ObtenerPath(id)

     If (Dir(path) <> "") Then
    'Dim f As New FrmImagen
    'f.PhysicalPath = path
    'f.Show True, Me
    'Shell path 'ShellExecute hWnd, "open", path, vbNullString, 
     vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    Debug.Print ShellExecute(hWnd, "open", path, vbNullString, vbNullString, 
    1)
    Else
    MsgBox "La imagen no existe.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "INFO"
    End If


    Exit Sub
    btnVer_error:
    MsgBox "No se encontró la imagen.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "INFO"
    End Sub
```

Comment: no entiendo el problema.. queres guardar muchos strings en un string?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es, que se guarde en un array los nombres que coinciden segun esto: variasimagenes = Dir(cdPhysicalPath & "Imagenes\" & tmp(2) & tmp(1) & 
    "\" & guia & "_*") y luego poder abrirlos al dar click en VER. Algunas guías tienen varias imágenes.

Comment: ok. pero no entiendo el problema. Que devuelve dir?

Comment: **Dir**, por ahora solo me devuelve un nombre de imagen: 013406617__1212.TIF , pero la guía **013406617** tiene 4 imágenes. Intento guardarlo en algún array o algo parecido para tratar de abrir todas las imágenes posteriormente. Lo que esta haciendo el **DIR ** es ubicar la ruta que le indico y obtiene el nombre según esos parámetros.

Comment: o sea, tu problema es como hacer que dir devuelva varios archivos en caso de que haya mas de uno?

Comment: Si señor. En c# si hago una función parecida(copiar todos las imágenes de cada guía), pero para ser franco en VB6 no tengo idea como realizar esto para abrirlas .

Comment: yo tampoco.. y tuve que buscarla en google.. y encontre la definicion de dir para vba.. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function.. pero para vb6, ni me acuerdo...

Comment: seguiré buscando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: fijate el objeto FSO (filesystemobject). Con ese podias recorrer carpetas y archivos mas facil

Comment: Estoy intentando eso, pero no me sale. :(

Comment: que quiere decir no me sale?

Comment: no logro guardar el array de los nombres de imágenes.

Comment: ni se que estas intentando.. no estoy con vos, y todo lo que me digas que probaste, no se que es... ni siquiera se que errores recibis...

Comment: No se preocupe, seguiré intentando.